# Operación con registro en Mongodb

Tags: mysql, mongodb, sql

Actualmente estoy usando Mysql, donde realizo operación matemática sobre un determinado dato:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(time+(timezone*3600)) as Fecha FROM test;
```

Es posible hacer la query en MongoDB o como lo harían?

Saludos.

Comment: que resultado obtienes con esa op? o que exactamente calculas?

Comment: De una "timestamp"(time) le sumo el timezone de un determinado país, luego lo convierto a formato datetime.

Comment: Hola, creería que se puede realizar, es decir tenes tanto la facilidad de resolverlo mediante Javascript o mediante el framework de agregación de MongoDB, quizá te ayuda este link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/